# import * as x and {y,z} from 'file'

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In short, how can I combine these two lines of code?

```
import * as php from './php';
import {str_replace, trim} from './php';
```

I can't find a syntax that works. I've tried things like

```
import {str_replace, trim}, * as php from './php';
```

N.B. this is ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262).

Comment: If you don't want two `import` statements you could do `import * as php from './php'; const {str_replace, trim} = php;`.

Comment: Good thinking @FelixKling. This was breaking eslint (`no-duplicate-imports`), but that should solve it in a nice clean way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine these in ES6 indeed. You can only use namespace imports or named imports together with a default import, but not with each other.

The solution is either to keep the two lines, or just use `php.str_replace` and `php.trim` everywhere in the code and drop the named imports.